# How to make content disappear when scrolling underneath the "header" area? Is there an example of this?

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, design

So I have a UX problem to solve -

Here's an example of the issue: 
[image]

As you can see, the message steps are nested underneath the folder. In order to view all of them, you would have to scroll from top to down and left to right.

Here's what I was thinking of how to solve this problem: 
[image]

In the image, the first picture represents what it would look like when you have the folders collapsed. The user clicks on the first folder for a couple seconds and then is transferred to a different screen where each of the steps are larger. When the user scrolls, they would only scroll from top to bottom, and the steps would "dissapear" under the header/folder area. All the steps would be at the same length and indentation, it's just the content that's within them that would change. To show that the steps are scrollable, the last one would be set to a lower opacity. In order to return to the first screen, the user would simply click on the folder for a couple seconds.

What do you guys think? Is this feasible? Is there another way to workaround this problem?

Comment: Why are they nested and not in a single list?

Comment: They're nested to show differentiation - it was an engineering requirement.

Comment: Is  this amount of questions and nesting realistic? or just an *edge case*? Also, not sure how things are in your place of work, but engineering comes AFTER design, they need to implement what you design, so you should tackle the problem first, find a more reliable solution then ask engineers to implement it

Comment: Is the engineering requirement that they are nested or that they are differentiated?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest this.
[image]

Keep the nesting aside like my wireframe. in here the user can identify the nesting order. when clicking the nesting area, left side same row getting highlighted(vice-versa) and all the data row can be seen from the bottom.